# Do plastic cutting boards harbor more bacteria than wood boards?

Tags: food-safety, cutting-boards

I've heard on numerous occasions that plastic cutting boards harbor more bacteria than wooden cutting boards. I use a large wooden cutting board often, but recently I've been finding it heavy and it sometimes leaves behind a flavour on food despite good cleaning.

Is there any objective evidence that plastic cutting boards harbor more bacteria than wood boards? I'm hoping there have been experiments that actually measure bacteria in these boards and perhaps compare them in real-life settings.

I've heard anecdotes and I've seen people provide plausible explanations why wood would be better for killing bacteria, but I haven't seen any hard data.

Comment: Putting wood board in dishwasher is... not the best idea, while plastic one would do just fine... So you may want to clarify what is acceptable method of cleaning for you.

Answer (score 7):

For the best sanitation, you want glass, or ceramic cutting boards. (Stainless steel is also good, but hardest on knives.)

But folks tend to not like any of these because they're hard on knives. It depends on your priorities, I guess. I prefer to err on the side of avoiding food-borne infections and other grossness, and I'm willing to replace or sharpen knives.

The problem with wooden cutting boards is that they're porous, so juices (especially from meat) can seep down into the wood and provide a rich nutrient broth for bacterial growth.

The problem with plastic cutting boards is that, every time you cut on them with a knife, you make a tiny groove in the plastic, which can harbor bacteria. These bacteria growing down in a groove or fissure are difficult to wash away, even with manual scrubbing. Also, *tiny* bits of plastic can end up in your food.

Plastic has a slight advantage over wood in that it's easier to wash. Throwing it in the dishwasher is the easiest, but won't get it completely sanitized, especially down in all of the knife-cut grooves. Your best bet for sanitizing plastic cutting boards is soaking them in a mildly diluted bleach (sodium hypochlorite) solution. For obvious reasons, none of that is really an option with wooden cutting boards. (*Small* wooden cutting boards can be sanitized by heating them, e.g., in a microwave, but this doesn't work well for large "butcher block" style, which are, in my experience, the most popular kind of wooden cutting boards that are seen.)

You really never want to use a wooden cutting board for meat. For meat, use something completely non-porous that can be easily cleaned, like glass or ceramic. In a pinch, you can use plastic, but make sure to sanitize it thoroughly and regularly.

A wooden cutting board is acceptable for fruit, vegetables, cheeses, breads, etc., and many people find it easier to work with than glass or ceramic. Plastic would also be fine for these items.

---

If you're interested in the research, there's quite a bit of it out there, but I can't claim to have read it all. The above is a general summary, based on my background in microbiology. The classic study is by Dr. Dean Cliver of UC Davis. You can surely find links to it online.

Another study, focused on commercial kitchens and the realities of induced wear (especially with regular cleaning), was conducted by Welker et al.: "[Bacterial Retention and Cleanability of Plastic and Wood Cutting Boards with Commercial Food Service Maintenance Practices](https://meridian.allenpress.com/jfp/article/60/4/407/167605/Bacterial-Retention-and-Cleanability-of-Plastic)", and this is freely accessible online. The conclusion (unsurprisingly) was that wood is more likely to wear out, developing "cracks […] sufficiently wide to entrap bacteria." Plastic is easier to clean than wood, and "after standard food service washing and sanitizing", wooden cutting boards promoted bacterial growth but plastic did not.

A study performed by Nese et al. (["Decontamination of Plastic and Wooden Cutting Boards for Kitchen Use"](https://meridian.allenpress.com/jfp/article/57/1/23/195718/Decontamination-of-Plastic-and-Wooden-Cutting)), also freely accessible online, confirms what I stated earlier about plastic being *generally* easier to sanitize, but the knife-cut grooves tending to interfere with cleaning. This paper also discusses the popular argument that wooden surfaces will *absorb* juices (bacterial inocula), thus inhibiting growth. This is true to some extent, but as other studies have shown, cannot be fully relied upon, especially as the wood ages and cracks, due to both use (knife cuts) and cleaning.

[The relevant advice on the US Food and Drug Administration](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/cutting-boards-and-food-safety) is, essentially, that both wood and plastic are acceptable, so long as you sanitize them frequency and replace them when they begin to become worn. (In my experience, people tend to know that plastic boards need to be replaced—not that they always do it—but they tend to assume wood lasts virtually forever, and purchase accordingly, spending lots of money on heavy, expensive wooden cutting boards.) The FDA also mentions bamboo as a possible option, since it's harder and less porous than hardwoods, meaning that it absorbs less moisture and is more resistant to scarring. I don't have experience with this, so I can't comment any further.

I leave you with a quote from Dr. Charles Gerba, a professor of microbiology at the University of Arizona, Tucson, who told [*Food and Wine* magazine](https://www.foodandwine.com/news/science-technology/fyi-your-kitchen-is-probably-dirtier-than-a-toilet-seat):

> In most cases, it’s safer to make a salad on a toilet seat than it is to make one on a cutting board.  There’re 200 times more fecal bacteria from raw meat on the average cutting board in a home than a toilet seat. Most people just rinse their cutting board, but poultry and raw meat can leave behind salmonella and campylobacter.
>
> People disinfect their toilet seats all the time, but they don’t realize that they really need to pay attention in the kitchen too.

Indeed. In case I haven't emphasized it enough throughout this answer, **the key is thorough, regular sanitation of your chosen cutting surface, no matter what it may be**.

Comment: FWIW, bamboo is also really hard on your knives.

Comment: IIRC A strategy used in commercial kitchens in the UK is color-coded cutting boards for different risk-categories of food. So the raw meat cutting board is only ever used for cutting raw meat.

Comment: Some dishwashers do have an option to sanitize your stuff using 95 C / 200 F hot steam. It is pretty good. Also, most plastics can be cleaned using NaON, hardly anything survives that, so if you're that serious about it, it can help a lot. Warning, NaOH needs to be used with respect.

Comment: The real question is: Are bacteria on cutting boards actually dangerous? Can they actually survive or reproduce when the board is relatively clean and dry? Is there any actual reason to go to great lengths to sterilise them?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm left wanting a bit though. I'm curious about actual studies that have looked at bacterial growth on plastic vs. wood cutting boards. If this data is included in one of the studies you cite then that information should be written in the answer rather than forcing the user off-site. You mention several plausible explanations as well, but as I mentioned, data is needed!

Comment: @Mołot You can pretty much use any harsh reagent that you want, including a strong base like NaOH or a strong acid like HCl. But it isn't necessary or even advisable. A typical household bleach solution will disinfect just as well, if not better, and is far safer for handling, not to mention easier to obtain and store. Laboratories that work with biohazard materials use bleach solutions to disinfect (although slightly higher concentration than normal household bleach), so there's really no need for anything exotic.

Comment: @Michael Yes, there is well-documented evidence of foodborne pathogens found on cutting boards, including *E. coli* O.157, *Salmonella* spp., *Campylobacter* spp., etc. Cutting boards used for raw meat are the most dangerous, as mentioned in the answer, because residues of juice get down into cracks or seep into the porous material itself, allowing for bacterial growth. All of the above-listed pathogens, with the exception of *Campylobacter jejuni* can replicate at room temperature and will grow down in pockets of moisture. Even if not growing, a small quantity is enough to cause disease

Comment: Yes, it's in all of the studies, @Behacad. I've provided a summary, which I think is sufficient. Anyone who would like to expand it, either by editing or with another answer, is more than welcome to do so. Other studies not explicitly cited here have been done in Germany, France, and Switzerland, swabbing household cutting boards and using PCR to detect microbial contamination. *E. coli* is a regular contaminant on cutting boards used to prepare poultry, although less than 10% of the time. But this type of empirical evidence is a lot less important or compelling to me.

Comment: @CodyGray What is in all the studies? That plastic boards are worse for bacteria than wood boards? That is the question I am asking. You do not answer this question, at least not directly. And if you do, I apologize, I missed it.

Comment: @Behacad Your previous comment said, *"I'm curious about actual studies that have looked at bacterial growth on plastic vs. wood cutting boards."* That's exactly what the answer talks about, and what all the mentioned studies are about. I'm not sure how to make it any more clear. No pressure to accept it, of course. You are welcome to wait for a more direct answer or one that you find more clear.

Comment: @CodyGray My issue is that I am looking for an answer to the actual question I posed: "Do plastic cutting boards harbor more bacteria than wood boards?" We don't have to get caught up in the semantics of what I mean by "harbor" and "bacteria" and "more", but I would be grateful if you could try to answer this question in plain English. You have suggestions about how to care for boards and why wood and plastic are both problematic, but don't seem to answer the actual question.

Comment: @CodyGray: What if you only use the board for cooked food?

Comment: @Michael Naturally, if you expose a cutting board to fewer or no sources of bacteria, then you are going to significantly reduce the chances of bacterial growth on it. But you can still have contamination, and you can still have stuck, decaying food particles that provide a home for bacteria from the environment. These bacteria will *probably not* make you sick (i.e., they're non-pathogenic), but still... kinda gross, in my opinion.

Comment: It's stated that plastic boards get cuts in them. So do wood cutting boards. Fairly recently, I read that it was found wood boards are actually safer than plastic. fwiw, for 32 years, I was involved a fast food chain where we always used plastic cutting boards and they still do today. We cleaned them with bleach, originally, then switched to quats. However, I very much like some kind of boards from Pampered Chef that feel like compressed cardboard but I have no clue what they're made of. I very much like cutting on wood boards.

Comment: @Behacad he answered it with the right answer, which is "it depends".  For example, if you hand-wash your plastic cutting boards, they tend to retain more bacteria than wooden ones.  But ... if you put your plastic cutting boads through the dishwasher or bleach them, then they're more sterile.  Except ... you can actually bleach wooden cutting boards too (I know from my years in food service) if you're willing to oil them regularly.  

In other words, your sanitization technique matters more than what the boards are made of.

Comment: Note that the wood vs. plastic debate has been going strong in state food safety regulators for quite some time (I remember it back to the 80's, and it wasn't new then).  It shows no sign of abating.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Where did he say it depends in that way? I read the part before the references and he says plastic boards have problems, wood boards have problems. He doesn't say "we don't know", "it depends", or "wood/plastic" is better. So I don't know the answer to the question, even if the answer is "unknown"

Comment: Look at the last sentence of his answer.  He even bolded it.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Are we looking at different questions? My question is (in brief): are wooden boards worse than plastic boards for harboring bacteria. He has bolded " the key is thorough, regular sanitation of your chosen cutting surface, no matter what it may be.". How is this an answer to that question?