# Primer on wooden cutting boards?

Tags: cutting-boards, wood

So I'm someone that is somewhat new to the kitchen, I like helping my mom in cooking but I don't do much alone because I'm usually swamped with university work but as the time to move out becomes sooner, I've been trying to learn about some kitchen essentials, particularly knife and prep work.

I have decent knowledge of using a knife as it is somewhat intuitive and the more I do it the more I'll get acquainted with it surely, but I've recently gotten a wooden cutting board (Proppmatt from Ikea for reference) without thinking ahead about the care it will need from me and the sources I've found online are a bit confusing, here's what I was able to gather:

1- these things need periodic oiling (and optionally board wax) and I have to oil it twice before the first use according to the instructions
2- I shouldn't cut raw meat on it or if I do I need to thoroughly clean it (though I've seen different takes on "thorough cleaning" ranging from vinegar solutions to diluted bleach so help with this would be appreciated)
3- It shouldn't be soaked in water (but should I wipe it dry or let it air dry?)
4- It shouldn't go in the dishwasher (good, I hate dishwashers)
5- I should avoid cutting heavily aromatic vegetables on it (?) like onions or garlic

So my question is that is this information reliable? Or am I jumping to the deep end too soon here with these things?

Also another question, for the raw meat thing, can't I just cover the board with something like a plastic wrap while I work on the meat then discarded it when I'm done thus avoiding the contamination? Or will the blade smacking against the wrap tear it apart and cause the board to get contaminated anyway?

Comment: This question is going to be a bit hard for people to answer, because you're asking a lot of different things.  You might want to focus the question a little more, specifically to clarify what exactly you're concerned about.  What I mean is, in a sense the answer to "am I jumping into the deep end" is *definitely not*. You don't *need* to do any of these things to use a wooden cutting board.  My parents had a wooden cutting board that went in the dishwasher, was never oiled, used for onions (probably not for meat).  It did eventually split apart - after 20 years.

Comment: And if you want advice for buying cutting boards, also see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/183/67

Comment: Abdul,  some of those questions don't yet have good answers on this board.  If you want to ask each of them as a separate question, feel free.

Comment: Some of the advice you seem to have been given is a bit over the top, wooden cutting boards are easy to take care of. I have never oiled any of my boards and I cut raw meat on them all the time. Just don't soak them in water for long periods and they'll last for many years.